# JavaFX - Error while trying to add function to start function

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I have a problem that I maybe don't see.

Topic: I have my class `Main`, that contain the window and I have a class `MainController` where I put all my function for the class `Main`.

#### Class `Main`:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        // primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
        MainController m = new MainController();
        m.testFunction();
    }
}
```

#### Class `MainController`:

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML private Label answer1;
    @FXML private Label answer2;

    public void testFunction()
    {
        answer1.setText("FIRST");
        answer2.setText("SECOND");
    }
}
```

When calling the `testFunction` in `Main.start` it give this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in     Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.MainController.testFunction(MainController.java:43)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:20)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Two days im trying to debug without success.

Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: Which is the 43th line of the `MainController` class?

Comment: Maybe the elements of controller has not been initialized and you get NullPointer Exception .Check the answer of Merve Sahin.

Answer (score 1):

Your MainController should implement `Initializable` and you should set the controller in your fxml : 
 e.g.

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="yourpackagename.MainController">
 .....
</AnchorPane>
```

Remove MainController from the start Method :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
// primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
primaryStage.show();
}
```

Now you can either test it when the MainController gets instantiated, or you could create a button and invoke an action method in order to test your method:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
   @FXML Label answer1;
   @FXML Label answer2;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
       if(answer1 != null && answer2 != null){
              answer1.setText("FIRST");
              answer2.setText("SECOND");
       }
      ...
   }

   ...
```

}

Comment: you don't need to check for null in method initialize cause when it enters in that method the elements of controller have been intitialized.

Comment: in some cases you do, sometimes the method is invoked more than once

Comment: I didn't knew that.If you want give me an example.

Comment: This is news to me too.From the [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers)(emphasis mine): *"However, when more control over the behavior of the controller and the elements it manages is required, the controller can define an `initialize()` method, which **will be called once** on an implementing controller when the contents of its associated document have been completely loaded"*.Of course you can call the method yourself on a controller instance that are created without injecting the necessary fields, but...

Comment: Even more, you don't *need* to implement `Initializable`, in which case you can make the `initialize()` method `private` and annotate it `@FXML`. Then you can assure that it is not called at any other time.

Answer (score 0):

You create a instance of the controller class that is not used with the fxml file and therefore `answer1` and `answer2` are not injected to the instance for which you call `testFunction`.

Assuming you correctly specified the controller class in the root element of the fxml file using the `fx:controller` attribute ([see *Introduction to FXML: Controllers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers)), you can get the controller instance created by the `FXMLLoader` during the loading process from the `FXMLLoader` instance, provided you use one:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
MainController m = loader.getController();
m.testFunction();
```